# An analogue of Noether's Problem for non-rational varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, birational-geometry, invariant-theory

For the sake of simplicity, let $\mathsf{k}$ be algebraically closed and of zero characteristic. Varieties are irreducible.

**The (linear) Noether's Problem** (which goes back to the early 1910's in Burnside's and Noether's work on invariants) is the following: let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space, and $G \subset GL(V)$ a finite group. When is the variety $V/G$ rational?.

Now this problem is intrinsically very nice and has a miriad of applications to moduli questions (cf. C. Böhning https://arxiv.org/abs/0904.0899; J-L. Colliot-Thélène, J-J. Sansuc, The rationality problem for fields of invariants under linear algebraic groups MR2348904 );
PI-algebras (E. Formanek, The polynomial identities and invariants of n×n matrices, MR1088481); the inverse Galois problem (D. Saltman, Groups acting on fields: Noether’s problem, MR810657); etc.
It is also interesting that the group actions that give a positive solution to Noether's Problem are very rich in nature.

Some questions closely related to this Problem have arisen in my research, and I wonder if they are adressed in some paper, or anyone knows something about then. I thought about these questions, but I could only think of examples coming from elliptic curves (such as multiplication by $[n]$ map), but these are, to my taste, a little bit too 'simple'.

**(Q1):** Let $X$ be a smooth projective curve of genus at least 1. What are the finite groups $G$ of $Aut_\mathsf{k} \, X$ such that $X/G$ is a smooth projective curves of the same genus?

**(Q2):** Let $X$ be a non-rational variety and $G$ a finite group of $Aut_\mathsf{k} \, X$. When $X/G$ is birationally equivalent to $X$ itself?

**Edit** Both questions were already answered in the comments. The questions were not difficult in the end.

Comment: (Q1): If $X$ is a smooth projective curve, and $G$ a finite group acting on it, then $X/G$ is smooth projective curve. Using Riemann-Hurwitz formula one shows that Q1 can only hold when $X$ has genus $0$ (always) or genus $1$.

Comment: For Q1, doesn't Riemann-Hurwitz imply that if genus is $>1$, the group has to be trivial? For the second, isn't it possible to take $X=Y\times\mathbb{P}^1$ for a non-stably rational $Y$ and take any finite subgroup of automorphisms of $\mathbb{P}^1$, acting on the second factor?

Comment: Thank you both. You  properly answer my questions.

Comment: Q2 maybe becomes more interesting if you ask for X general type, rather than X non-rational... it's not immediately clear to me whether there should be an easy counterexample.

Comment: @dhy to my understanding the first counter-example for rational $X$ (the affine space in particular) is due to Saltman in 1984 or 1985

Comment: @jg1896 Sorry, by counter-example here I actually mean example where $X$ is birational to $X/G$. The reason is that in the general type case for most $X$ and $G$ it will be possible to distinguish $X$ and $X/G$ via natural invariants, e.g., the $h^{0,i}$.

Comment: @dhy Don’t general type varieties only have finitely many rat’l self-maps? It seems to me a general type example is thus impossible (bc iterating a self-map of positive degree would give infinitely many self-maps).

Comment: @DanielLitt good point!